# How to specify availability zone with AWS EKS Fargate cluster with eckctl?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I'm learning Kubernetes, and am trying to create an AWS EKS Fargate cluster with the following config simple file

```
kind: ClusterConfig
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5

metadata:
  name: sandbox
  region: us-east-1
  version: "1.18"

fargateProfiles:
  - name: fp-default
    selectors:
      # All workloads in the "default" Kubernetes namespace will be
      # scheduled onto Fargate:
      - namespace: default
      # All workloads in the "kube-system" Kubernetes namespace will be
      # scheduled onto Fargate:
      - namespace: kube-system
  - name: fp-sandbox
    selectors:
      # All workloads in the "sandbox" Kubernetes namespace matching the
      # following label selectors will be scheduled onto Fargate:
      - namespace: sandbox
        labels:
          env: sandbox
          checks: passed
  - name: fp-fluxcd
    selectors:
      # All workloads in the "fluxcd" Kubernetes namespace matching the
      # following label selectors will be scheduled onto Fargate:
      - namespace: fluxcd
```

I get the following error. How can I specify the availability zone in above config file?

```
[✖]  AWS::EKS::Cluster/ControlPlane: CREATE_FAILED – "Cannot create cluster 'sandbox' because us-east-1a, the targeted availability zone, does not currently have sufficient capacity to support the cluster. Retry and choose from these availability zones: us-east-1b, us-east-1c, us-east-1d, us-east-1e, us-east-1f (Service: AmazonEKS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnsupportedAvailabilityZoneException; Request ID: 7c5c4544-4fe5-4ed5-96a8-099d60e1e5ab; Proxy: null)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the eksctl [config file schema](https://eksctl.io/usage/schema/#availabilityZones).

```yaml
kind: ClusterConfig
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5

metadata:
  name: sandbox
  region: us-east-1
  version: "1.18"

fargateProfiles:
  - name: fp-default
    selectors:
      # All workloads in the "default" Kubernetes namespace will be
      # scheduled onto Fargate:
      - namespace: default
      # All workloads in the "kube-system" Kubernetes namespace will be
      # scheduled onto Fargate:
      - namespace: kube-system
  - name: fp-sandbox
    selectors:
      # All workloads in the "sandbox" Kubernetes namespace matching the
      # following label selectors will be scheduled onto Fargate:
      - namespace: sandbox
        labels:
          env: sandbox
          checks: passed
  - name: fp-fluxcd
    selectors:
      # All workloads in the "fluxcd" Kubernetes namespace matching the
      # following label selectors will be scheduled onto Fargate:
      - namespace: fluxcd

availabilityZones: ['us-east-1b']
```

Comment: I totally missed that, and have that page bookmarked and constantly viewed. Thanks.